# IE issue for font-awesome and Roboto not working on Server

Tags: internet-explorer, yeoman-generator, roboto, fontawesome-4.4.0

I have used yeoman generator for the project structure and included bower components for font-awesome and Roboto. The fonts load fine on grunt serve. I have also tried running the index.html created in the dist folder which again works fine. Even the .WAR file created using Jenkins build when hosted on my local tomcat work fine. But when the code is deployed on Server Roboto and Font-awesome do not render properly. I have checked the network tab to see if fonts are getting downloaded which is visible. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps not a complete answer, but hopefully it helps... I've had a similar problem the cause of my troubles was that by default all intranet sites in IE were running in compatibility mode.  When I explicitly disabled that option the fonts worked fine.

If that is your problem this tag will force IE not to use compatibility mode 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">`

Comment: fwiw this turned out not to be the case..It switched the document model ok, but the browser is still in 'compatibility view' and in some scenarios fonts still don't load. see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634781/loading-fonts-in-ie-11-compatibility-view-with-edge-document-model