# loading fonts in IE 11 Compatibility view (with Edge document model)

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

Having a few issues with IE11 compatibility view. I'll explain what I mean by that then outline the specific problem type i'm having.

My site is on the corporate intranet, server is returning a UA-Compatible header with a value of 'Edge'.  Effect of this is that if I open the debug tools I I see the Document mode is correctly set to Edge. BUT the console logs a message saying the browser is in compatibility view ( *XX is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked.*) and I see some rendering differences. I can't seem to force it out of compatibility view so I've decided to try live with it.. which leads to my next issue.

I'm using the google font api, by default I'm loading all the fonts weights at once.

IE, at least in compatibility view as I've described, only returns one of font weights I'm using.  I've seen this behavior fixed elsewhere by having a conditional comment which then loads them individually

```
<!--[if gt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500" /> 
<![endif]-->
```

Trouble is my IE as far as as the document mode is concerned it's Edge (document.documentMode = 11, devtools show document mode : Edge) o and doesn't pay any attention to the conditional comments.

So the question is this is there a way of forcing IE in the mode I've described to load these webfonts correctly?

Comment: What's the value of document.documentMode (in the console or on the page)?

Comment: document.documentMode returns '11'  and in the devtool Document Mode shows as 'Edge'.  which makes sense.

Comment: Hi, you should be using Enterprise Site Mode Lists to manage your intranet assets back compatibility.... it over-rides IE Compatibility settings...The message "XX is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked." must be generated by developer code..back compatibility messages are only generated by the dev tool and displayed on the Emulation tab, not on the console.. See the Emulation tab of the dev tools for the correct Emulation mode details. Search your code for the message string "Intranet sites" to find out where its generated.

Comment: ITs unusual for intranet sites to access resources from external domains.. web search for 'google dorks' for more details about FBI guidelines for govt. domains. IE has settings for "Ignore font sizes styles specified on web pages" and the font tag is depreciated...check your settings on the Accessibility button of the General tab of Internet Options. Replace <font> tags with <spans> and classes. if document.documentMode==11 and document.compatMode =='backCompat' then that would explain the incorrect compatibility message in the console.

Comment: @RobParsons your comments definitely constitute an answer, better to write it as an actual one so that future visitors with the same problem can easily find this information (questions without answers don't end up on the top of SO or Google searches).

Comment: "<the compatiblity message>  must be generated by developer code", this is inaccurate.. you can see a similar message in the console if you add say google.com to the 'compatibility view' list in IE.  This is a standard IE mesage.

Comment: @RobParsons  yeah, better if you can add this as an answer.. I have a few clarifications, better to do them there..